# CSS vehicle animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a tractor moving across the screen. I've got it working perfectly on my screen, however I want it to work across different platforms (only included -webkit-). When I re-size, the tractor is fluid, but the wheels aren't. How can I make them adjust together?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="tractor">
        <img src="img/tractor-700px.png" alt="tractor">
    </div>
    <div class="wheels">
        <div class="b_wheel">
            <img src="img/b_wheel.png">
        </div>
        <div class="f_wheel">
            <img src="img/f_wheel.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my main CSS:

```
.tractor {
   width: 380px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
   left: -5%;
}

.tractor img {
    width: 100%;
}
.tractor::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url('img/steam.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -37%;
    left: 56%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.f_wheel {;
    width: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 66.5%;
    left: 13%;
}

.f_wheel img {
    width: 100%;
}

.b_wheel {
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 58.8%;
    left: -7%;
}

.b_wheel img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And CSS for the animation:

```
.tractor {
    -webkit-animation: tractor-bounce 3s ease-in-out infinite,
                       tractor-go 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.tractor::after {
    -webkit-animation: steam 4s 2s infinite;
}

.f_wheel,
.b_wheel {
    -webkit-animation: wheel-spin 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.f_wheel {
    -webkit-animation: front-wheel-go 10s ease-in-out forwards,
                       wheel-spin 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.b_wheel {
    -webkit-animation: back-wheel-go 10s ease-in-out forwards,
                       wheel-spin 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}


/*  Keyframes - WebKit only
------------------------------------------ */

@-webkit-keyframes tractor-bounce {
    50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) translateY(-3px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes tractor-go {
    100% { left: 70%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes steam {
    40%  { opacity: .8; }
    60%  { opacity: 1; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-15%, -35%) rotateZ(20deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wheel-spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(50deg); }
    100%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(480deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes front-wheel-go {
    100%   { left: 88%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes back-wheel-go {
    100%   { left: 68.5%; }
}
```

JSFiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/0j5L92vh/1/

[PS - This is my first post here so many thanks in advance! Let me know if I need to include anything else.]

Comment: always nice to have a jsfiddle so people can try some things: http://jsfiddle.net/0j5L92vh/

Comment: If you could provide a js fiddle that would be great!

Comment: EDIT: @Stefan - I updated the above jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/0j5L92vh/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/0j5L92vh/1/)

Comment: The animation is super cool ! but maybe you could do a fiddle without the animation? The problem you're having here doesn't have anything to do with the animation - it's probably a positioning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem.

I utilized the .container div you have provided to keep everything positioned relative
to your tractor image.  You can see the changes in the css code that made will make
it work in non webkit browsers. It will not work on versions of Internet Explorer before number 9.

The changes I have made are only to your css.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/h324j6u6/113/

css:

```
     .container{
    width: 380px;    
    position: relative;

    /*bind the animation and set its properties*/
    -webkit-animation: tractor 10s linear 0s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: tractor 10s linear 0s;
}
/*bind the wheel-spin animation*/
.f_wheel,
.b_wheel {
    -webkit-animation: wheel-spin 10s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: wheel-spin 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}
/*bind the tractor bounce-animation*/
.tractor {
    -webkit-animation: tractor-bounce 3s ease-in-out infinite,
                       tractor-go 10s ease-in-out forwards;

    animation: tractor-bounce 3s ease-in-out infinite,
                       tractor-go 10s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.tractor img{

    width:100%;
}

.b_wheel {
    width: 190px;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
    left: -7%;
}

.b_wheel img {
    width: 100%;
}

.f_wheel{
    width: 125px;
    position:relative;
    top: -258px;
    left: 65%;
}

.f_wheel img {
    width: 100%;
}



/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes tractor {
    0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {left:400px; top:0px;}
    75%  {left:600px; top:0px;}
    100% {left:800px; top:0px;}
}



/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes tractor {
     0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {left:400px; top:0px;}
    75%  {left:600px; top:0px;}
    100% {left:800px; top:0px;}
}




/*standard browser animation*/
@keyframes wheel-spin{

    0% { transform: translateX(0px) rotate(50deg); }
    100%   { transform: translateX(0px) rotate(480deg); }    

}
/*webkit browser animation*/
@-webkit-keyframes wheel-spin{

    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(50deg); }
    100%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(480deg); }


}
/*webkit tractor-bounce animation*/
@-webkit-keyframes tractor-bounce {
    50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) translateY(-3px); }
}

/*standard tractor-bounce web browser animation*/
@keyframes tractor-bounce {
    50%  { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateY(-3px); }
}
```